# Principal Component Analysis in Python: Analytical Mistake

Tags: python, pca

I'm implementing a `Principal Component Analysis` for face recognition in `Python` without making use of the already defined `PCA` methods in `numpy` or `OpenCV`. But my results are literally rubbish.

I read the documentation and algorithmic description at `OpenCV`'s [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html). But some things aren't clear.

- If `X = {x1, x2, ..., xn}` then I believe it isn't the X matrix used when calculating the Covariance matrix? But that you've to subtract the mean etc. as explained in the first two steps.
- The eigenvectors must be sorted corresponding to the eigenvalues in descending order. Do you have to sort while looking at the absolute value of the corresponding eigenvalue or not? Anyway the order is not the main issue as I plot all the eigenvectors, so I can rearrange them accordingly. I think I made an analytical mistake.

I implemented the following:

```
MU = X.mean(axis=0)
for i in range(n):
    X[i,:] -= MU

S = (np.dot(X, X.T) / float(n))
#Hermitian (or symmetric) matrix.
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = numpy.linalg.eigh(S)
eigenvectors = numpy.dot(X.T, eigenvectors)
for i in range(n):
    eigenvectors[:,i] = normalize_vector(eigenvectors[:,i])
```

Note that the sample values are stored in the rows and not the columns. So `X` is of shape `nxd` with `n` the number of samples and `d` the dimension of the samples.

[image]

The above image is the reference. The first is the mean, the following three are the largest eigenvectors.
The below image is my result. The first is the mean, the following are all the eigenvectors in some order. But they seem not to match the result.

The `cv2.PCACompute(X, 6)` still produces better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question is quite well answer [here](http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280452).

For the second one the answer is you need to order the eigenvectors according to the value of their corresponding eigenvalue. For that, you can use python `np.argsort()` and then reverse this order (argsort order from smaller to bigger):

```
indexes = np.argsort(eigenvalues)[::-1]
eigval = eigenvalues[indexes]
eigvec = eigenvectors[:,indexes]
```

---

Checking your code, I've just found a couple of problems:

1. Now, you are getting **all** the eigenvectors, you are ignoring the `nb_components` parameters, you should take just the vectors you are asked for. This is made with

   `eigenvectors = eigenvectors[:,indexes][0:nb_components]`
2. For normalizing vectors (inside pca function), you are using a for loop from 0 to `n`, but if you are asked only for, lets say, 3 eigenvectors, you only will have 3 columns. To solve it, iterate from 0 to `nb_components`.

Apart from that, your code works perfect. I tried it only taking 3 Principals components and I got 6/6 as final result. In my opinion, the difference when showing the eigenvectors is just a representation problem when casting from float to uint8 to use imshow.

And about the negative eigenvalues, it is just a matter of `eigh`. As eigenvalues shows the variance in a direction, we care about absolute value but if we change a sign, we also have to change the "direcction" (eigenvector). You can make this multiplying negative eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors with `-1.0` (see [this](http://statmaster.sdu.dk/courses/ST02/module05/index.html#SECTION00040000000000000000)):

```
s = np.where(eigenvalues < 0)
eigenvalues[s] = eigenvalues[s] * -1.0
eigenvectors[:,s] = eigenvectors[:,s] * -1.0
```

You can also solve this using `numpy.linalg.svd`([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html)), but is should be slower than `numpy.linalg.eigh`.

To sum up, this is the code I came up from yours (I deleted all comments when coping here to make it shorter):

```
def pca(X, nb_components=0):
    [n,d] = X.shape
    if (nb_components <= 0) or (nb_components>6):
        nb_components = n

    MU = X.mean(axis=0)
    for i in range(n):
        X[i,:] -= MU

    S = (np.dot(X, X.T) / float(n))

    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(S)

    s = np.where(eigenvalues < 0)
    eigenvalues[s] = eigenvalues[s] * -1.0
    eigenvectors[:,s] = eigenvectors[:,s] * -1.0

    indexes = np.argsort(eigenvalues)[::-1]
    eigenvalues = eigenvalues[indexes]
    eigenvectors = eigenvectors[:,indexes][:,0:nb_components]

    eigenvectors = np.dot(X.T, eigenvectors)

    for i in range(nb_components):
        eigenvectors[:,i] = normalize_vector(eigenvectors[:,i])

    return (eigenvalues, eigenvectors, MU)
```

Comment: Ok the first question is nicely explained, but now I'm getting a bit confused of the division by n or n-1, because both seem to be used on some sites. For the sorting I still have the question for the negative eigenvalues. I think 300, -100 and 1 are sorted 300, -100, 1 or are they sorted 300, 1, -100? I will try to normalize the resulting eigenvectors after multiplying with X.T.

Comment: Covariance matrix is computed dividing by `n`, I've also seen some implementation with `n-1`, but I can't tell a reason (I've been using `n` for a long time with good results). About negative eigenvalues, you shouldn't have any, as covariance matrix [Positive Semi-defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties) and those matrix only have [positive eigenvalues](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~njw/Teaching/Math271C/Lecture_03.pdf).  If you can't find the reason post a link to your test img and I can try to find something more.

Comment: You're right on the float64->uint8 conversion. If I eliminate the conversion in createX, the models look much better.